# Spring: How to protect a login page against csrf (without breaking changes)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf

I have a Java project which uses Spring.

I need to protect the login page against CSRF attacks.

At the moment, my Spring xml configuration file contains

```
<http>
    ...
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Due to the size of the project, I can't afford to change all the pages and protect them against CSRF right now, but I'd like to at least protect this one, which I feel is one of the most important ones. In particular, I can't protect the /logout endpoint, which uses a GET request (it would be a breaking change).

How can I just protect the login page, without the logout request ?

I tried to do this:

```
<bean id="csrfMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg name="pattern" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <constructor-arg name="httpMethod" value="POST"/>
</bean>
<csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfMatcher" />
```

and add this piece of code in the existing login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

However the logout request is also affected by this change, which it would like to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: Based on the age of your configuration, I'm guessing your view is in JSP?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: Then you should generally be using Spring's taglib; it will automatically handle the CSRF parameters for you when you use it to create a form.

Comment: Can you please detail what I should add in my jsp page to make this work ? I am really not familiar with jsp, though it's what we are using.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have a feeling you are probably right, but I don't really know how to make it work. Could you please give a more detailed answer on your suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you only use these 4 http methods (get, post, put, delete) this regex would ignore all paths except login

```
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/login).*", "get"),
                    new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/login).*", "post"),
                    new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/login).*", "delete"),
                    new RegexRequestMatcher("^(?!/login).*", "put")
                    ).disable());
```

Comment: Thanks. What would be the xml equivalent ?